# Über die Semantik von "unmittelbar"

Tags: meaning, semantics

Seitdem ich dem Wort *unmittelbar* begegnet bin, finde ich es als Fremdsprachiger schwierig dessen präzise Bedeutung zu begreifen.

Ich habe dennoch versucht mir eine grobe Idee darüber zu machen, und stelle mir die Bedeutung von *unmittelbar* wie folgt vor:

> Im Kontext der natürlichen Zahlen, stehen die Zahlen Eins und Zwei unmittelbar nebeneinander

Das würde dann heißen, dass es kein weiteres Objekt zwischen Eins und Zwei gibt.

Was würdet ihr dazu sagen?

Comment: Ein Synonym von "unmittelbar" ist *direkt*, das in vielen Sprachen ein passendes Gegenstück hat, ein Antonym *indirekt*. Das hilft möglicherweise beim Verständnis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deine Annahme ist korrekt. *Unmittelbar* bedeutet in deinem Beispiel, wie du selbst vermutet hast, dass keine andere Zahl dazwischen liegt, sondern dass *zwei* direkt auf *eins* folgt.

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unmittelbar) führt insgesamt drei verschiedene Bedeutungen auf. In allen dort aufgelisteten [Beispielen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unmittelbar#Bedeutunga) lässt sich die Bedeutung jedoch so umschreiben:

> Es liegt nichts (Bedeutendes, Erwähnenswertes) zwischen A und B.

Ob es sich um etwas Greifbares oder Abstraktes, etwas Räumliches oder Zeitliches handelt, spielt dabei keine Rolle.

Answer (score 3):

Die Bedeutung von *unmittelbar* erschließt sich besser, wenn man dessen Etymologie zurückverfolgt. Es geht zurück auf das lateinische *immediatus* oder dessen griechisches Kognat *ἄμεσος*. Beide lassen sich auf ein entsprechendes Stammadjektiv zurückverfolgen, im Lateinischen ist das *medius* in der Bedeutung *vermitteln*.

Gleichermaßen lässt sich *unmittelbar* auf den Stamm *Mittel* (wie *Mittel und Wege*, nicht wie *mittlere*) zurückführen. Ein mittelbarer Stoß ist einer, den man nur spürt, wenn er durch etwas Anderes *vermittelt* worden ist. Demnach ist *unmittelbar* das, was keiner Vermittlung zwischen beiden Einzelnen bedarf.

Da zwischen den ganzen Zahlen 1 und 2 keine andere ganze Zahl steht, gibt es nichts, was zwischen ihnen vermitteln könnte, sie sind also *unmittelbar* nebeneinander.

Quelle: [DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=unmittelbar)

Comment: ＋１ weil Etymologie immer hilfreich und auch in fremden Sprachen leicht zu recherchieren.